# Delete history files without showing a dialog

Tags: c#, browser, browser-history

I am trying to delete history files from web browser in C# as in the following post:

[How to clear browsing history using WebBrowser control in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931795/how-to-clear-browsing-history-webbrowser-control-c-net)

But I don't want to show any message dialogs while I am clearing the history.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Is this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201) of any help?

Comment: @rene: That KB seems about clear the *cache*.

Comment: yes this linke is who i want to delete history files,do u have any other linke to delete history from ie toolbar,example when you write one chare in ie toolbar like goo it will be auto complete from history and show google.com...

Comment: worke like this code without dialogbox System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8");

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your question is related to how I can run next line without showing command window

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8");
```

You can do that using next code

```
try
{
    var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8");
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanke you very much ,Do you have any code to do same thinks on Chrome , opera , firefox

Comment: I have try this, and no dialog was shown; not sure why is showing on your system;