# How to clear IE cache webdriver Selenium Grid DesiredCapabilities and InternetExplorerOptions

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, caching

My original question was unclear I was really looking for a way to start IE with a clean session running on the Grid. I thought the Selenium solution to this was broken, turns out it was how I was using it :facepalm: So I have updated my question to reflect that part.

So my issue is that I cannot get IE to start in a clean session when I run it on Selenium Grid. I have done a fair share of research and implemented the `DesiredCapabilities` that is supposed to handle this for IE. 
`internetExplorerCapabilities.SetCapability(ieOptions.EnsureCleanSession.ToString(), true);`

But sadly this is not working and I have opened a ticket with the selenium developers if you are interested in [tracking it.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2676)

Comment: Your question is, "How do I run a process with arguments in C#?", and here's an answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx: `Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");` (untested).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear browsing history using WebBrowser control in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931795/how-to-clear-browsing-history-using-webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Updated question to reflect more of what I was after and to try and differentiate it from the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `ieOptions.EnsureCleanSession.ToString()` will return `true` or `false` and not `ensureCleanSession`. To set the capability:

```c#
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;

var capabilities = (DesiredCapabilities)options.ToCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "11");

var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.34.161.112:5555/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: How would I supply the `RemoteWebDriver` with both `options` and `DesiredCapabilites`?

Comment: Simply add your capabilities to the capabilities returned by `options.ToCapabilities()`.

Comment: I am unsure how to do this trying something along the lines of `options.AddAdditionalCapability(DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer().SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName).ToString(), "internet explorer")` but this does not compile.

Comment: The name of the browser is already set. For other capabilities, see updated answer.